# Ubuntu Openstack Console Error "Failed to connect to server (code: 1006)"

Tags: command-line, 18.04, openstack, virtual-console

[image: Instance Console]

I have installed Ubuntu Openstack using MicroStack snap [installed:          stein]  on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

When I try to connect to the console of newly created instances... I'm getting the following error "Failed to connect to server (code: 1006)"

The "Send CtlAltDel" button was greyed out... Not working and unresponsive.

Any help greatly appreciated

[image: Instance Console Error]

Comment: Be more specific, _does not work_ does not mean anything without context

Comment: Sorry... I get the following error... "Failed to connect to server (code: 1006)"